# Javascript delete operator doesn't work when ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to delete the index in each loop after an ajax success?

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
    var Container = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('search_storage'));
    if (Container) {
        $.each(Container, function (index, value) {
            $.ajax({
                url: base_url+'search/add_search',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {'type_name': value['type_name'], 'type_id': value['type_id']},
                success:function(data) {
                    delete Container[index];
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: And where are you checking whether `delete` works or not? Also is `Container` an array or an object?

Comment: No, where in the code? Right after `$.each`, right?

Comment: after ajax success

Comment: Hmm normally using asynchronous calls inside a loop would get you unexpected results, can you tell us if the last index is deleting?

Comment: Yes, it's working.... When I put the delete operator after ajax success  nothing happens

Comment: set ajax request `async: false` because your loop has completed its iterations but possibly ajax request taking long time or there's another way, you can make a callback function which calls back after success.

Comment: @Ali Shahbaz I tried, still doesn't work

Comment: Did you check that your `Container` have values at this line `delete Container[index];`?